# How to filter a String in java with specific range (email format)

Tags: java, string

I have a String in Java called `Kiran<kiran@gmail.com>`. I want to get String just kiran@gmail.com by removing other content.

```
String s1= kiran<kiran@gmail.com>
```

Output should be `kiran@gmail.com`

Please help me out in solving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to parse email addresses, I'd recommend to use the [InternetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html) class. It is part of Java EE (if you are using Java SE you need to add the **javax.mail** dependency).

That class is able to parse an String containing an email address like yours.

```
String s1 = "kiran<kiran@gmail.com>";
InternetAddress address = new InternetAddress(s1);
String email = address.getAddress();
```

I think this way:

- Your algorithm is automatically standards-compliant
- Your code is cleaner than using regular expressions to extract the email address.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following thing.

```
String s = "To: John Smith <john@smith.com>, Janes Smith\n"
            + "<jane@smith.org>, Tom Barter <tom@test.co.uk>, Other \n"
            + "Weird @#$@<>#^Names <other@names.me>, \n"
            + "Long Long Long Long Name <longlong@name.com>";
    s = s.substring(3); // filter TO:
    System.out.println(s);
    // Use DOTALL pattern  
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)<([^>]+)>\\s*,?",Pattern.DOTALL);

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while(m.find()) {
        // filter newline
        String name = m.group(1).replaceAll("[\\n\\r]+", ""); 
        String email = m.group(2).replaceAll("[\\n\\r]+", "");
        System.out.println(name + " -> " + email);
    }
```